# unknown opcode using ARM NEON instructions with Microsoft ARM assembler

Tags: assembly, windows-mobile, arm

I am using the Microsoft ARM Assembler v15.00.20720 (armasm.exe) that came with Visual Studio 2008. I am trying to build an assembly file that uses ARM Cortex-A8 NEON instructions, but I am getting "unknown opcode" errors for `VLD1` and `VST1` instructions
My processor is a TI OMAP 3430.

My command line:

```
armasm -32 -CPU ARM8 myfile.asm  myfile.obj
```

For example:

```
VLD1.64 {d0-d3}, [r1@128]! ; unknown opcode VLD1
VST1.64 {d4-d7}, [r3@128]! ; unknown opcode VST1
```

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2008's armasm supports ARM architectures only up to ARMv6 (ARM11) which does not include NEON. ([the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253568%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says only up to v5 but I think it got extended in SP1.)

For ARMv7 you can use either a recent WinCE (=Windows Embedded Compact) Platform Builder or Visual Studio 2012 (though I'm not 100% sure if VS2012 supports targeting WinCE).

Comment: It looks like NEON instructions are only in the A-series processors, not the underlying ARMv7 cores. http://arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php I tried using the CE6 Platform Builder armasm (v15.01.31217) and I get a similar error. 
VS2012 cannot target WinCE. (yet) Though, I may try it anyway. All I need from it is the object file, right? Once I get that, VS2008 should be able to link it.

Comment: You should get Windows Compact 7 tools, they [support ARMv7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154428): "Windows Embedded Compact 7 supports ARM-licensed technologies for architecture v5, v6, v6 MP, and v7."

Comment: The WEC7 armasm (v15.01.50304) also does not support NEON. I suspect that NEON is part of the Cortex-A series architecture which is not supported by the WEC7 ARM assembler.

Comment: I just installed VS2012 RC. The ARM assembler in there (v11.00.50522) seems to accept the NEON instruction set. Unfortunately, VS2008 says the produced object file is "invalid or corrupt". ARGH!

Comment: @PAulH that's very strange, because I've seen some OMAP BSPs for WEC7 and I think they did use NEON. I'll need to check it later.

Comment: I'm sure the BSP from TI includes an ARM compiler that can handle NEON. I just don't happen to have access to one of those right now. I was hoping I could do this with just Microsoft tools.